# If statement with two or more conditions

Tags: shell, if-statement

I was modifying an script didn't know how to write more than one condition in an if statement. I want to connect the two condition with an AND.

```
if [ envoi1 -eq 2 ];then
    if [ envoi2 -eq 0 ];then
        echo 'Ahora mismo.'
        envoi = 1
    fi
else
    if [ envoi2 -eq 1 ];then
        if [ envoi1 -eq 1 ];then
            echo 'Situacion Normal.'
            envoi = 1
        fi
    else
        echo 'Raruno'
        envoi=`expr $envoi1 + envoi2`
    fi
fi
```

Now i use nested if to do the same but the code it's not so clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if [ $envoi1 -eq 2 ] && [ $envoi2 -eq 0 ] ; then
  envoi = 1
fi
```

Comment: Ok, like in C/C++. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness, `[ $envoi1 -eq 2 -a $envoi2 -eq 0 ]` is *possible*, but [*not recommended*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031#np2). Also, [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, you can use `[[` as follows:

```
if [[ $envoi2 -eq 1 && $envoi1 -eq 1 ]]; then 
    echo "Situacion Normal."
    envoi=1
fi
```

However, `[[` is not POSIX and will not work if you are using the `/bin/sh` shell. So if portability is desired use:

```
if [ $envoi2 -eq 1 -a $envoi1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Situacion Normal."
    envoi=1
fi
```

Also note that when assigning variables you should not have any spaces on either side of the `=`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [`[ $envoi1 -eq 2 ] && [ $envoi2 -eq 0 ]` is more portable than using `-a`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031#np2)

Comment: These two are not the same. Latter does not abort as soon as possible.